# Сколько возможно комбинаций при 9-ом значном коде по этому правилу?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Код: `0Н0 Ч0Н 0Ч0`

Где:
`0` — любая рандомная цифра от 0 до 9.
`Н` — любая НЕЧЁТНАЯ цифра.
`Ч` — любая ЧЁТНАЯ цифра.

При таком правиле, сколько возможно комбинаций 9 значных кодов?

И ещё такой вопрос, насколько сложно будет человеку подобрать (угадать) такой код? :)

Может быть ещё можно какое-то правило добавить, чтобы было максимально сложно угадать код?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На первое место - 10 цифр, на второе - 5, на третье... — а потом перемножьте их все.

Comment: Harry, как? :) Подскажите, пожалуйста. Немного не понял как посчитать. Можете привести пример?

Comment: 10^5\*5^4 = 62500000 комбинаций.

Comment: Harry, cпасибо большое. Подскажите ещё вопрос, насколько сложно подобрать код по этому правилу? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае независимого размещения цифр количество вариантов перемножается. Например, сколько всего двузначных чисел? Первая цифра - 9 вариантов, вторая - 10, 9*10=90.

У вас 5 знакомест, в которые можно записать любую из 10 цифр, плюс 4 знакоместа по 5 цифр. Итого

```
10*5*10*5*10*5*10*5*10 = 62500000
```

Много это или мало - зависит от того, как это подбирается. Если это механический замок, в котором надо руками крутить колесики - очень много. Если компьютерная программа проверяет за микросекунду верность кода - то очень мало, на минуту работы. Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, надо знать, сколько времени выполняется проверка одного варианта.